# Code signing ClickOnce manifest vs assembly, for a solution deployed by Windows Installer. Which one do I need, and how?

Tags: visual-studio, code-signing, code-signing-certificate

I have code-signed my Visual Studio project's "ClickOnce manifest" using a provided USB token certificate.
However in the same tab there is also an option to "Sign the assembly". Since I deploy this project using a setup project (Windows installer) and not by ClickOnce publishing, I assume I need this signed too? Or maybe only this, and not the ClickOnce manifest?

But if this is the case, how can I sign it using "select from store"? There is only an option to sign it using an either existing, or a new certificate file (PFX or SNK). My certificate is a SafeNet USB token, and there is no file provided. Sectigo claim they cannot sign using a file, so how can this be done? (if it is indeed even needed)

Thanks